# Filtering Outlook Mails on a date range and downloading attachments that satisfy a given sub condition?

Tags: python, outlook, email-attachments

### i was trying to make a Python script to automate certain aspects in my outlook account in a manner that:

*whenever i receive emails with attachments containing a certain SUBJECT they are automatically downloaded to a folder on my system.* *Here is my code:*

```
import win32com.client
import os
current_path = os.getcwd()
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
for m in messages:
    if m.Subject == "TEST MAIL":
        print("message body:", m.body)
        attachment = messages.Attachments
        for x in attachment:
            x.SaveASFile(os.path.join(current_path, x.FileName))
```

*The above code doesen't work and throws an exception:pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)*

Comment: How are you matching the date range?

Comment: I thought of using the date time library is there a better way to filter mails for 3 days? Than using date time lib?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
 x.SaveASFile(os.path.join(current_path, "Test1.csv"))
```

with

```
 x.SaveASFile(os.path.join(current_path, x.FileName))
```

Comment: but what about the multiple attachments

Comment: Is there a way to download them too

Comment: What about multiple attachments? Your code loops through all of them, does it not?

Comment: No it doesn't loop through all messages I tried your solution ie..... x.FileName but I got an error instead "AttributeError: <unknown>.Attachments